# New SoundCloud HTML5 widget animation on track finish

Tags: soundcloud

The new update for the html5 widget has added an animation at the end that hides the waveform and shows sharing options and embed codes.

This breaks the effect that was desired in one of my clients sites that relies on the widget as its audio engine.

Is there a way to stop this animation or revert back to the older widget as it worked fine as it was.

The site is http://www.bushytunes.net

Play a track, skip to the end as see for yourself.

Thanks, James

-------UPDATE-------

On messing around with the iframes css in chrome web inspector, ive come across the .sound__sharePanel DOM element, all i require is the simple option to add display: none to this and the problem will be fixed.

I do belive i am passing a false boolean to the sharing paramater when loading the player iframe. Shouldn't this handle hiding the element as the api docs state that this parameter will 'Show/hide share buttons/dialogues.'

Comment: Hey James, we'll look into this.

Comment: This should be fixed now, sorry for unexpected behaviour.

Comment: Hey, Thanks for the speedy fix, much appreciated.