# SoundCloud HTML5 widget: share panel covers waveform when audio finished

Tags: html, widget, embed, soundcloud

When the audio completes in the HTML5 version of the SoundCloud widget, the share panel appears and covers the audio waveform. The user can replay the audio; however, the share panel doesn't disappear, nor does there seem to be any way for the user to hide it. Nor is there any way to prevent the panel from appearing in the first place, which is the ideal option.

The "sharing" parameter is set to false in my embed code.

Here is the embed code I'm using:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="100%" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=http%3A%2F%2Fapi.soundcloud.com%2Ftracks%2F87283114&buying=false&sharing=false&liking=false&show_artwork=false&download=false&show_user=false&show_bpm=false&show_playcount=false&show_comments=false&color=568ED4&theme_color=DDD9C3"></iframe>
```

Replicated in Firefox and Chrome.

Again, this is an HTML5 issue only. The Flash version works properly.

Note that a similar issue also occurred but was fixed in the Flash version:

[New SoundCloud HTML5 widget animation on track finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13404731/new-soundcloud-html5-widget-animation-on-track-finish)

Comment: Yep, I can see the bug too. I'll make an issue in our tracker and hopefully get a fix out this week. Thanks for the report.

Comment: The issue appears to be fixed now, thank you.